# Can i change a command with input from a discord message?

Tags: input, discord.py

I wanna make a moderation bot.
In that moderation bot is an autorole command but i have one question about this.
This is the command:

```
async def on_member_join(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Member") 
    await ctx.add_roles(role)
```

But i want to make it that people can type !autorole @[Role] and then if someone joins they get that role instead of the `Member` role. I don't know how to get an input from discord. And i could't find anything about in on the internet. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do that via a global variable, i.e. a variable that all functions can access and modify.

Your code could look something like this:

```py
role_to_assign = None

@client.command()
async def autorole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    global role_to_assign
    role_to_assign = role

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.add_roles(role_to_assign)
```

Comment: But how does this work if the bot is in multiple servers? Does the role then change for all servers or only for that server?

Comment: If you want to have each server have a different role to automatically assign, you can create a dictionary where the keys are the servers and the values are the roles. This is how it would look like: https://pastebin.com/GQMf6CGW

Answer (score 1):

You can store role name in `json`, `yaml` or `txt` file. Then you can change that role whenever you want.

```py
@client.command()
async def autorole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    file = open('autorole.txt', 'w')
    file.write(role.id)
```

Then when you add auto role to someone, you can access this file, get the role id, then add to the member.

Also, it's better to call the parameter `member` instead of `ctx` in the `on_member_join` event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role_id = open('autorole.txt', 'r').read()
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = int(role_id)) 
    await member.add_roles(role)
```